# Unable to display data after casting to an array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an entity called **Folder** and I am trying to print out an array of created folders. I am sure my data is saving when creating a folder with the following code, the `println`does execute with the correct data;

```
@IBAction func createFolder(sender: AnyObject) {

        //Save new event
        let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Folder", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        let folder = Folder(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc!)


        folder.title = createFolderField.text
        folder.date = NSDate()

        println("\(folder)")

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)
    }

    exit()

}
```

But when trying to print out the array of folders the console outputs a nil or 0 when trying to count after creating a folder. If my saving code is fine then I must be doing something wrong when creating the array.

```
let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

var folders = [Folder]()

func loadData() {

    var error: NSError?
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Folder")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]

    self.folders = moc?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as! [Folder]
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    loadData()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("\(folders.count)")

    loadData()

}
```

Does anybody have any ideas where I may be going wrong saving/fetching the data ?

Comment: Sorry if i am misreading the question but you seem to be printing out the count of folders before you populate it by calling loadData?

Comment: @NeilHorton School boy error, I presumed viewWillAppear would populate it. However after calling load data before the println() it was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling `loadData()` after trying to println therefore the array was not populated. I was expecting `viewWillAppear` to populate it.